# How do I added an object to a vector<object> that's inside another class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
#include "player.h"

class team
{
public:
 team();
 void addPlayer(player);
 void deletePlayer(int);
 double getTotalCost();
 int getPlayerCount();
 double inBank();
 string toString();

private:
 player a;
 int playerId;
 double bank;
 int i;
};
```

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "team.h"


team::team()
{
 vector <player> a;
 player a;
}

team::addPlayer(player)
{
 a.push_back(a);
}
```

If more info is needed please ask. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: since you don't like to waste time properly formatting your code, I can't see why other people should waste theirs trying to decode it.

Comment: the title of the question is meant to be a title, not a question. It shouldn't include details like the name's of your classes, etc.

Comment: Yeah... no. I won't answer that until you put some effort into the question.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.  We are not your personal developer... are we??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you meant:

```
#include "player.h"
#include  <vector>

class team
{
public:
 team();
 void addPlayer(player);
 void deletePlayer(int);
 double getTotalCost();
 int getPlayerCount();
 double inBank();
 string toString();

private:
 vector<player> a;
 int playerId;
 double bank;
 int i;
};

#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "team.h"


team::team()
{
}

team::addPlayer(player p)
{
 a.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: it's better to write team::addPlayer(const player &p) {...}

Comment: Would be nicer if `addPlayer` took the argument as reference to const (`void team::addPlayer(const player & p)`).

Comment: this is good but for some reason now it's giving me these errors

Comment: Error 4 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int x:\c++\assignment 2\assignment 2\team.cpp 10 team

Comment: Error 5 error C2556: 'int team::addPlayer(player)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void team::addPlayer(const player)' x:\c++\assignment 2\assignment 2\team.cpp 10 team

Comment: Error 6 error C2371: 'team::addPlayer' : redefinition; different basic types x:\c++\assignment 2\assignment 2\team.cpp 10 team

Comment: add 'void' before team::addplayer. and please read any of the thousands of c++ tutorials available online

Answer (score 0):

You shoud have your vector variable a member of your class or create it on heap a keep the pointer to it. Now you are creating your vector on a stack in teem constructor. It will deleted when constructor is finished.
 Also you can't use name a for both player and vector. I recommend you to read some C++ books first.

Answer (score 0):

There's so much wrong with this I don't know where to begin, you declare a SINGLE player, here:

```
private:
    player a; // why not just call every variable in your program "a"?
```

And then in your constructor of the team:

```
team::team()
{
    vector<player> a;  // a vector that will be destroyed on exit from constructor
    player a; // another single player, but you've just defined 'a' so you should get a compiler error along the lines of redefinition.
}
```

I suspect you want something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "player.h"

class team
{
private:
    std::vector<player> m_Players;   // players

public:
    void addPlayer(const player& _player) { m_Players.push_back(_player); }
}; // eo class team
```

Answer (score 0):

What do u need ? Store players in your class team ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(int id)  {   m_id = id; }
    int GetId() {return m_id;   }
private:
    int m_id;
};

class team
{
public:
    team(){};
    void AddPlayer(Player p) {m_arr.push_back(p);}
    size_t Size(){  return m_arr.size();}
    Player GetPlayer(size_t index) {return m_arr[index];}
private:
    vector<Player> m_arr;
};

void main()
{
    team t;
    for (int i =0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        t.AddPlayer(Player(i));
    }

    for (int i =0; i < t.Size();++i)
    {
        cout << "Player [" << i + 1 <<  "] with id: " << t.GetPlayer(i).GetId() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: in detail better way to pass Player by const reference... or pointer if Player object big